# Do humans have enough biological differences to be grouped into races or subspecies?

Tags: human-genetics, population-genetics, taxonomy, classification

After my online research on the subject, I learnt that, biologically speaking, many scientists believe that there is no such thing as a race. *Homo sapiens* as a species is only 200,000 years old, which has not allowed for any significant genetic diversification yet, and our DNA is 99.99% similar. I've read statements that there can be more genetic variation inside a racial group than between different racial groups, meaning that, for example, two individuals from the same "race" can have less in common with each other than with an individual from another "race".

[Wikipedia on Race (human classification) quote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_(human_classification)):

> Scientists consider biological essentialism obsolete, and generally discourage racial explanations for collective differentiation in both physical and behavioral traits

---

**Q1:** If *Homo sapiens* has no races (according to biologists), why are we so different morphologically? (hair/eyes/skin colour and even athletic performance seem to differ between human populations)

**Q2:** Is it common for other species too, when genetically close populations have very different morphological traits? Are there any other mammal or animal species that exhibit biological diversity comparable to human diversity, and how do taxonomists treat these species? (excluding intentionally bred domestic species to keep the comparison fair)

---

*The question has been paraphrased to emphasize that it is the **biological** debate that is in question, not the **sociopolitical**. I.e., why is there no consensus in evidence and opinions of scientists?*

Comment: Why did you remove _"to the point that we cannot tell an individual of one racial background from another based on a DNA sample"_ from the question? This makes the first sentence in the answer obsolete.

Comment: You have to note that taxonomy is *artificial*

Comment: [Here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1369848615000655) a recent paper that mixes philosophy and population genetics that is probably of interest. I haven't read it though.

Comment: See also [Does it make sense to classify all humans in a single species?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/57555/does-it-make-sense-to-classify-all-humans-in-a-single-species)

Comment: Some random googling gives [this article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4756148/) on the topic (more searching might give other articles with different conclusions; I haven't made any comprehensive effort) which finds that *...human races/continental groups or clusters have no natural meaning or objective biological reality.*

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Firstly, it's not true that you can't tell racial background from DNA. You most certainly can; it's quite possible to give fairly accurate phenotypic reconstruction of the features we choose as racial markers from DNA samples alone and also possible to identify real geographic ancestral populations from suitable markers.

The reason that human races aren't useful is that they're actually only looking at a couple of phenotypic markers and (a) these phenotypes don't map well to underlying genetics and (b) don't usefully model the underlying populations. The big thing that racial typing is based on is skin colour, but skin colour is controlled by only a small number of alleles. On the basis of skin colour you'd think the big division in human diversity is (and I simplify) between white Europeans and black Africans. However, there is *vastly* more genetic diversity within Africa than there is anywhere else. Two randomly chosen Africans will be, on average, more diverse from each other than two randomly chosen Europeans. What's more Europeans are no more genetically distinct overall from a randomly chosen African than two randomly chosen Africans are from each other.

This makes perfectly decent sense if you consider the deep roots of diversity within Africa (where humans originally evolved) to the more recent separation of Europeans from an African sub-population.

It's also worth noting that the phenotypic markers of race don't actually tell you much about underlying heredity; for example there's a famous photo of twin daughters one of whom is completely fair skinned, the other of whom is completely dark skinned; yet these two are sisters. This is, of course, an extreme example but it should tell you something about the usefulness of skin colour as a real genetic marker.

Comment: Yahoo answers say you can't tell race from DNA... that's why I mentioned it. I also never heard this in crime investigations or detective stories... are you sure we can? Just double-checking, by no means I imply that my sources are credible.

Regarding skin colour, we can also consider that the skin colour of a Caucasian can vary from pale-white to red to dark-brown at different levels of UV exposure. These changes are only in the phenotype, not in the genotype.

What about athletic performance though? It's something more than just skin tinge. It must be related to organ systems, muscles, etc.

Comment: It depends what you mean by race; because race isn't actually meaningful you obviously can't reconstruct it. However, given a DNA sample it is possible to make a good approximation of the appearance of the person the sample is from. I don't think such a reconstruction would be reliable enough for law enforcement purposes, but it's pretty good none-the-less.

Comment: @Herman Suppose that in some sport it is an advantage to be very tall. Then because all genetic variation of humans is in Africa, you would expect the tallest people of the world to be in Africa. But you would also expect the smallest people in the world to be an African people. Similarly, in Africa you would find those who can sprint fastest. But you would also find in Africa those which are the slowest runners. So expect all variation to be on that continent. Also remember that those Africans who were deported to the Americas as slaves, all came from a small area on the west coast of Africa.

Comment: I think you mean to illuminate variable expressivity in the last paragraph.

Comment: does Europeans are no more genetically distinct overall from a randomly chosen African than two randomly chosen Europeans are from each other ?

Comment: @Qbik, yes, I believe it is, and I mentioned this information in the question too. I suggest you go to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_(human_classification)#Fixation_index) part of Wikipeida's article on Fixation Index. There are also two links there to original studies, if you won't to go even further.

Comment: @Jack Aidley, how do "deep roots" of African populations and "more recent separation of Europeans" explain higher genetic diversity in Africa? Sorry, it doesn't make "perfectly decent sense" to me. Europeans inherited these deep roots too when separated, no?

From my ecology background I know that there are theories that claim that evolution occurs faster in the tropics, but I never thought about it in the context of human populations. That could explain your point, but I don't think that's what you meant.

Comment: @Jack Aidley, as to your first paragraph, have a look at [this question](http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/7384/5392). If you learn something new and change your opinion, you might want to edit your answer a little.

Comment: @Herman, from the answer to the question you link "So to sum up, DNA analysis can tell the gender, skin color, and eye color of the suspect, but very little about height and weight, and virtually nothing about age."

Comment: @Herman: Evolution follows a branching, hierarchical structure (broadly, it's more complicated than that) and Europeans group _within_ the various African populations, i.e., they're essentially a subpopulation of a particular African population.

Comment: @JackAidley, do you mean the founder effect? A subset of the original African population that founded European nations did not represent the whole genetic pool of the original African population, is it right?

Comment: @Herman: No, although that can also be a factor. Have a look at this image - http://bit.ly/1iHOMss - and note how there is no clade that includes both Africans but not the Europeans. This is because the European population is a subpopulation of the African population. The two African populations shown are as different from each other as the European population can be from the first African population. In reality, there are many more distinct African populations than shown here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12474/discussion-between-herman-and-jack-aidley)

Comment: I'm not sure skin color is a good example of characteristic that is used to classify people into race. In an ordinary life yes, race mostly equals skin color, but it seems that 20th century racial scientists relied more on skull measurements and facial features.

Answer (score 37):

Well, that's just it, we *don't* actually have much phenotypic variation. For example, compare this:

[image: Collection of human faces]

to this:

[image: Collection of dogs]

or this:

[image: Collection of cat faces]

---

Or this:

[image: Six human babies]

to this:

[image: Five dogs]

---

*This* is phenotypic variation:

[image: Collection of pigs]

---

So, as I hope is clear from the images above, phenotypic variation among humans is *tiny* compared to other species. We just notice small differences much more because, well, it's us so little differences are much more noticeable.

Comment: This ridiculously obvious illustration somehow put the issue in a totally different perspective for me. Quite an eye-opener. I think this is a brilliant answer, thank you for the effort.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure how useful comparing natural variation (human phenotypes) to artificial variation (dogs, cats and pigs) really is. Are you humans really less phenotypically variable than wild animal species? I guess ring species might make a good comparison?

Comment: @JackAidley birds of paradise are "natural" as far as that goes. In any case, the point is moot, whether the observed variation has been affected by humans or not, it is clear that the human species shows relatively little variation compared to what can be seen in others.

Comment: @terdon: The bird of paradise are not a species, as you note in your answer and I don't think it's clear - at all - that humans show relatively little phenotypic variation. I would say that humans are probably on the high side (likely due to the huge range that humans occupy).

Comment: @JackAidley the statement is one I remember from university. Anecdotal evidence like that presented in my answer seems to confirm it and I was _tought_ it years ago. I'll see if I can find a proper reference but it certainly looks to me like we have far far less variation than other species.

Comment: Dogs are deliberately hybridized.

Comment: I also think it is misleading to compare human phenotypical variation and phenotypical variation that is the outcome of artificial breeding. To make this argument you would have to place human phenotypic variation within the range of phenotypic variation from a large number of "natural/wild" species. And comparing variation in birds of paradise (family Paradisaeidae) would only be valid if compared to Hominidae, i.e. including chimps, orangutans, extinct [Hominini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hominini) etc (still ignoring that taxonomic families cannot really be considered equal).

Comment: "excluding intentionally bred species to keep the comparison fair"

Comment: @Rodrigo yes, that was added _after_ I posted this answer.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I'm having a hard time estimating any objective scalar value of the variation here. Nevertheless, it seems like humans still are on the top of the league regarding phenotypic variation. Look at the western jackdaw for example, four different subspecies identified mostly on the base of some slight colouring variations.

Comment: @Alex I'm normally a stickler for quantification, but I think the point is made quite well qualitatively. Your rebuttal is neat -- the jackdaw has similar variation to us. But that itself is justification for ignoring the subspecies divisions in jackdaws as much as imposing subspecies labels in humans! [@bshane offered a great summary of subspecies here](http://biology.stackexchange.com/a/38771/3553) that demonstrates how arbitrary a term "subspecies" is.

Comment: All pictures exhibit some degree of phenotypic variation, and if you see all these people in person and close up, you'll notice yet more variation than with isolated faces. Even the smell is different (but how have we lost our smell senses recently!). So your answer is considered good because you used beautiful pictures, though your reason is completely subjective.

Comment: @Rodrigo of course there's *some* phenotypic variation. And of course you, as a human whose eyes and entire social structure are centered around the necessity of differentiating between the different members of your tribe, would see variation. That, however, does not mean that humans exhibit a lot of phenotypic variation. That said, no, this isn't a very good answer and yes, of course you'd need some hard, quantitative data to be able to answer correctly.

Comment: You say: What is race? "a lot of phenotypic variation". Seeing 29 upvotes in this answer reminds me of the fact that *Homo spp* are about 80% vision, but much less reason.

Comment: @Rodrigo what? I never said that race is a lot pf phenotypic variation. This answer is just pointing out that humans have far less phenotypic variation than other species. In any case, I'd appreciate it if you'd stop now. You first commented on this question in 2014, so just downvote it and walk away.

Comment: By the way, races of dog are really *races*? To me they seem only a few genetic loci that can control a limited range of morphological and behavioral traits. They're probably not the kind of "general genetic diversity" that some have been proposing for us humans.

Comment: Your example cannot show how less phenotypic variation, actually. The pathways between genes and morphology are far from linear. And we should not walk away from questions that bother us, should we?

Comment: @Rodrigo this isn't a discussion forum. If you disagree with an answer, you can downvote and you can leave a comment explaining, if you like. But engaging in long discussions in the comments is against the rules. I also have no interest in defending this answer from your accusations given that I dont' make the claims you think I'm making. So if you insist on badgering me, at least take it to [chat] where it belongs. Ideally, just downvote, express your disagreement and leave me alone though.

Comment: Sorry, but I think this is of relevance to anybody following this page. If we need to go to chat, the message appears automatically, like "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55986/discussion-between-terdon-and-rodrigo).

Comment: Human Fst is comparable to cats' Fst: https://emilkirkegaard.dk/en/?p=7753

Answer (score 17):

*I decided to summarize a competing hypothesis to make our answers more balanced. I also tried to address the question about the degree of human morphological diversity compared to other animals.*

---

According to Woodley (2010), it is plausible that *H. sapiens* does not belong to one species and subspecies (i.e. is polytypic). Some of the data he uses to support this hypothesis could be useful for answering our question. He claims that *H. sapiens*, which is often considered monotypic, **posses higher levels of morphological diversity, genetic heterozygosity and differentiation than many animal species which are considered polytypic.**

Woodley cites a study by Sarich and Miele, who claimed that morphological differences between humans, on average, are equal to the differences among *species* within other mammalian genera (excluding species bred for domestic purposes), and are typically more strongly marked than in other animals.

However, morphological differences are known to be caused by little genetic differences too, like in the case of domestic dogs, which are still considered to be one species. Therefore, Woodley presented further evidence that looked on these inconsistencies in classification using allele frequencies and genetic diversity.

He presented data from a wide range of studies, which compares genetic diversity of various mammalian species based on heterozygosity (H), which is a common indicator for genetic diversity, and describes whether both alleles are the same or not on a studied locus. According to this data (which you can find in the linked paper):

- Chimpanzees exhibited H of 0.63-0.73, which is very similar to H found in humans (0.588 - 0.807), however, chimpanzees are divided into four subspecies.
- Some species like the grey wolf even exhibited a lower H (corresponding to lower genetic diversity) than humans (0.528 vs 0.588 - 0.807), while the grey wolf has been divided into as many as 37 subspecies.

**This data suggests that humans are more diverse both morphologically and genetically than some of the other mammalian species that have been divided into subspecies.**

References:
Woodley, M. A. (2010). Is *Homo sapiens* polytypic? Human taxonomic diversity and its implications, *Medical Hypotheses, 74*, 195-201. doi:10.1016/j.mehy.2009.07.046 ([full-text PDF](https://lesacreduprintemps19.files.wordpress.com/2011/06/woodley-2009-is-homo-sapiens-polytypic-human-taxonomic-diversity-and-its-implications.pdf))

Comment: It's a political question. They think (or pretend?) they're fighting racism denying human races. At the same time, a country with more species and subspecies receive more funds for conservational programs (see my answer).

Comment: How would that translate into multiple species? From my uninformed perspective it looks like a species with a high but uniform heterozygosity is possible, so that there would be absolutely no clear cluster or even that any attempt to build clusters based on this would lead to weird effects such as people ending up into a different species than their siblings.

Answer (score 11):

**Bias**

When you say `phenotype` you mostly mean "skin color", "size of the nose", "hair color", "shape of the eyes", "height", and some others. All these traits that we manage to find to explain [population structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Population_stratification) among humans. But you forget all the rest of the phenotypic diversity. If you would choose 1000 randomly chosen traits (external morphology and other stuff) and make a [PCA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis). Will the main axes explain much of the inter-subpopulation (or inter-racial) diversity? I am not sure about that. One cannot use one subset of the total phenotypic or genetic variance and use it in order to define several species within what was previously thought to be one. It is not because two genes are associated with the same population structure that one can define two different species.

**scientific observations vs biased intuitions**

You say:

> [..] is it reasonable to use a genetic approach to races and claim that biological races do not exist, while it seems to be a poor indicator, when it comes to comparison of phenotypes of human populations.

Similarly, one could say

> Bats look like birds. We consider them as being mammals just because that is what scientific observations (genetic data or in-depth observation of the phenotypic variance) says. Should we follow scientific explanations when my personal bias intuition tells me that these observations are poor indicators?

The answer is yes if you want to increase your knowledge and no if you just want to be comforted into what you think you already know.

I have to confess though that I don't know much about phenotypic or morphological variations among humans. And I'd be curious if someone could give some words about that and whether or not much of the phenotypic and morphological variance is explained by what we consider being racial groups. It might be possible that very little of the total phenotypic variance is explained by racial groups but quite a lot of the face morphological variance is explained by racial groups.

**Concept of species**

For species that can reproduce exclusively with sex, we tend to use the concept of reproduction isolation to define a species and I really don't think that there is a pair of racial groups are sexually incompatible (however you delimit the racial groups). Eventually, there might have some slight inbreeding depression but I am not sure.

You might want to have a look at [this answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/39664/how-could-humans-have-interbred-with-neanderthals-if-were-a-different-species/39669#39669) to understand the semantic difficulties behind the concept of species

Comment: I would be very, very surprised to find out that any two racial groups cannot reproduce: not only we are one species, we are also one subspecies, and we share over 99.9% of the same genome. The world would be a totally different place if this was true, from the sociopolitical perspective. It might happen one day though. I hope collectively we'll be much wiser when and if it does happen.

Comment: Yes, that would be immensely surprising indeed! But I don't think any study ever reviewed cases of reproduction between all "considered social groups".

Comment: On the other hand, it also means that no one has ever noticed any suspicious trends in child mortalities from cross-racial parents to think about such a survey. 

I also believe that gentlemen from the Third Reich would be very interested in this question, and they conceivably could do some research, which wasn't published because the results were negative. It's just my guess though, and I'm no specialist in history.

Comment: Remi, sorry, I'm not familiar with PCA, and the Wikipedia page is intimidating. Was your first point that we share so much traits in common that the ones that distinguish us from each other are statistically non-significant?

Comment: "For species that can reproduce exclusively with sex, we tend to use the concept of reproduction isolation to define species and I really don't think that there is a pair of racial groups are sexually incompatible" But this reproductive isolation is not only due to genetic incapability, but to purely practical geographic isolation as well, right?

Comment: But other animal races are only defined genetically? Or is it (or has been for millennia) more a biogeographic concept? Or, for any species where there is no genetic data, we just can't say anything about races?

Answer (score 11):

It seems to me that many answers to this question suffer from the nasty habit of "political correctness". As a zoologist, I never heard of somebody sequencing the whole DNA of any species to decide when to use or not the term "race". If a group of animals comes from a side of a river, and the other comes from the other side, and they have one or a few distinctive features (color of chest pelage, tuffs of hair in the sides of head, etc), that's enough to call them both different races (or even subspecies). Of course some geographical isolation has taken place, although it hasn't been long enough to divide the two (or more) populations into full species. The same logic should be used to humans, right? Maybe some folks believe that, pretending there are no human races, then the question of racism is "solved"? Bad logic, to me.

Look at http://www.worldbirdnames.org: they cite 10,518 extant species of birds and 20,976 subspecies. About 2 subspecies per species. How do they do that? (No DNA for most of them.) Subspecies/races are usually from different regions (like human races), their vocalizations are usually different (like human races) and their colors sometimes vary (not as much as in human races). My point is: there is NO SCIENTIFIC REASON to say there are no human races, if we're using zoological reasoning. (Unless we are not animals anymore!)

For mammals, http://www.catalogueoflife.org/col/browse/classification/kingdom/Animalia/phylum/Chordata/class/Mammalia/match/1 cite: 4,843 species, 2,998 infraspecific taxa. Again, if someone show me they did complex DNA analysis for most of those infraspecific taxa, and those analysis showed that variation inside races is smaller than between races, THEN I will be forced to agree with them.

Comment: Maybe, but the "why?" question is beyond our scope here, I asked the "is it?" question, which is purely biological. If you improved your answer by expanding on your experience as a zoologist when it comes to defining subspecies and removed the "why?" question of your own -- I, personally, would like your answer much more :-)

Comment: I just inverted your question: "If human populations have several distinct phenotypes, why (they say) there are no human races?" Or, from other point of view, I questioned your first "If" in the title. It's not just a biological question, to me it seems much more a political one. How many biological races have been described? Or subspecies? Take a look at IUCN Redlist, for instance, or Zoological Records in many universities. Do you really think they scanned their DNA in depth? There's no biological reason for a different approach on human beings. As I said, it's just politics.

Comment: I think you make a fair point... I might paraphrase my question. Why paraphrasing? Although intuitively I agree with you that it might have something to do with politics, it's not really something that I wanted to discuss, and it's probably not even allowed to be discussed on Biology SE. If we do, someone will ask: "Well, **how do you know** that it's all just politics", and here we go, it becomes a **debate** with no science behind it, just opinions.

Comment: Rodrigo, ok, most of subspecies and "races" in zoology don't have DNA analyzed but are still considered to be separate. However, in the case of humans it **is** analyzed, so it would make sense to apply this information if it indicates that humans cannot be grouped in races, wouldn't it? (whether that's what our DNA indicates or not is another, not mentioned by you, question)

Comment: What is the definition of race? Is it the same as subspecies or semispecies? http://www.ucl.ac.uk/taxome/jim/Sp/Sub-semi.pdf By this article, what human DNA says is that human races are not human semispecies nor subspecies. According to Mayr definition (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_%28biology%29), "races" is a concept that requires less genetic divergence than subspecies.

Comment: @Rodrigo However, generally, I would argue that when classifying non-human animals into races we either know or imply a very low level of gene flow between races/subspecies. We know that this is not the case for humans.

Comment: While I see your point about there being races, I very much doubt you'll be able to support the use of the term as it tends to be used today. With the criteria you state, the Scots and the English would be different races, for example. If we take variations in vocalizations and geography as indications of race, each country will represent a race of its own. So while your argument does indeed support the existence of human races, it does not support the idea that those races are defined by color alone.

Comment: Well, all this should be properly studied. I just don't agree with the "findings" that "there are no human races".

Comment: Couldn't you also phrase this as "genetic diversity of most animal species is probably overstated, because morphological differences which aren't sufficient to establish the existence of subspecies in humans are used to claim the existence of subspecies in other animals" -- or in other words "look at how there aren't human races -- therefore there probably aren't  as many animal races in most cases where we assume that there are animal races". I don't understand how your answer shows that there are human races, in other words. It just seems to show that zoological reasoning is bad.

Comment: @Will Actually I'm asking: What is the present definition of race? Is it the same definition we used 30 years ago?

Comment: Oh OK that makes sense

Comment: You claimed that vocalizations & hair/skin coloration are evidence of substantial genetic differences between races; but this is flawed. Fair-skinned individuals, if exposed to UV radiation develop darker skin. While this isn't permanent for them, the fact that the change can happen within an individual's lifetime indicates that it is not a dramatic difference in genetic / evolutionary terms. 

Human vocalization is dependent on the environment. If you adopted an infant of another race and raised it, it would speak in your language & accent; not that of its biological parents.

Comment: @Kent.Green people who lived in cold climates for millennia developed a white skin, and those who lived in warm climates for millennia developed a dark skin. Both are well adapted to their environments. That's the biological definition of race, not the amount of DNA involved in the adaptation.

Comment: That's exactly my point, while superficially races appear very different; the amount of DNA involved in the distinction is relatively small, which is the reason that "race" does not make sense as a classification on the level of species or subspecies. Moreover, you still haven't addressed the differences in "vocalizations" which are even more contingent on environmental conditions than skin pigmentation.

Comment: @Kent.Green Races are indeed less "discrete" entities than subspecies. I just want to know how much DNA divergence people want to use as part of their definition, since I've not seen such "objective" definition anywhere, just a systematic denial of the existence of human races (motivated by some kind of "political correctness" it seems). About human vocalization, you're right, it's not the best trait, but it does show that human populations remained isolated for long periods. That's the general definition of "geographic races" used in zoology, or I've been learning it wrong for so many years?

Comment: Here is a source that might be what you're looking for: "The biological definition of race is a geographically isolated breeding population that shares certain characteristics in higher frequencies than other populations of that species, but has not become reproductively isolated from other populations of the same species."
- http://www.biologyreference.com/Ar-Bi/Biology-of-Race.html#ixzz4dVXjcmSb

Comment: Not objective at all. Skin color, hair type, nose format... those already are "certain characteristics". By this definition there are human races.

Comment: This is a bad answer, opinion-based and apparently driven by some kind of political views, and proposes an incorrect definition of 'race' or 'subspecies. People in the past didn't use genetics to identify subspecies, but they do now, and for good reason. Take a read of [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3737365/) to educate yourself.

Comment: @user438383 Thanks for the link. Dog races are called dog subspecies?

Answer (score 4):

First you can take a look at this diagram:

[image]

You can make a google image search for "Cavalli Sforza" and get a lot of similar diagrams. This diagram is using a concept known as [genetic distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_distance) by [fixation index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixation_index). This is a way to measure how different different ethnic groups are genetically.

Basically what you do is you compare how many differences there are on average between two humans from the same population and between two humans from two different populations. The same method can be applied to animals. There is no "threshold value" where you can say that two groups of people or animals have become different enough that they can be defined as "different races".

Traits such as skin colour are regulated by a very small handfull of genes so even if we have different skin colours that does not mean that we differ much genetically speaking.

Lions and Leopards can have fertile offspring and live basically in the same habitat in Africa. I do not know if crossbreeding is known to have occured in the wild. Probably a hybrid has lower fitness than the original species.

Comment: So, what's your point about human races?

Comment: I would say focus on the actual differences instead of the name. Differences as far as Fst, IQ etc. goes. "These are the differences between group A and group B". I like the term "ancestral group", nobody can really deny that they have an ancestry.