# How are cells different depending on the ethnic origin?

Tags: cell-biology, dna

I recently came across [an article](https://www.cityofhope.org/news/kittles-lack-of-ethnic-diversity-in-cell-lines) about the fact that cell-lines provided by merchant entities to give cells to researchers, were tagged by ethnic origin. The article especially speaks about ethnic origin of African and European. The article points out that the lack of diversity in available cells has consequences on the effect of the therapies made by researchers, since they can work only on limited European (which are the majority of the provided cells). I understand that this concerns stem cells (am I correct?).

I understand of course the problem, but what remains unclear to me is : **How are cells different depending on the ethnic origin? (especially protein coats of the cells that affects the vulnerability to diseases)** The first answer I have is that they could be distinguished by their DNA (obviously genes coding skin color will be different).

With my researchs I found other articles that gave some information:

- This lacks of diversity has an impact on the [prostate cancer](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7219314/), so does it mean that prostate cells are different depending on the ethnic origin?
- Some [viruses](https://journals.asm.org/doi/10.1128/JVI.01124-08) have different expression in different ethnic origins

Answer (score 14):

The article is particularly concerned with [personalized/precision medicine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personalized_medicine): tailoring therapy to specific individuals based on their genetic background.

The article is in particular talking not about stem cell lines, but about cell lines derived from patients with cancer. These cell lines are studied to understand what made those cells cancerous, to both understand mechanisms of cancer and develop treatment.

> How are cells different depending on the ethnic origin?

The issue raised is not a *specific difference*, but rather the *unknown*. If you only study variation among European-derived cell lines, you cannot possibly understand human-wide variation. Further, if you have just one cell line labeled as "African-American" and use studies with this cell line to make decisions about how you're going to treat all Americans with Black/African ancestry, and that one cell line is also mostly of European origin, you shouldn't expect that research to result in good outcomes for African-American/Black patients.

An example of how this might work is that a bunch of study into cancer cell lines identifies some specific mutation associated with cancer, and some pharmaceutical treatment that is highly effective in cancers based on that mutation (perhaps an antibody-based treatment). The next step would be to identify patients who carry that specific mutation or where that mutation is present in biopsied tissue, to give them that customized therapy. However, if all the cell lines you study come from people with European ancestry, only people with European ancestry are likely to have any of those specific mutations, and everyone else is left out.

In particular, [African populations are more genetically diverse than populations anywhere else](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/14414/do-humans-have-enough-biological-differences-to-be-grouped-into-races-or-subspec), presumably because humans first evolved in Africa and subsequently traveled elsewhere. Therefore, studying mostly people of European ancestry merely because they are the dominant group in a specific high-wealth country like the US is leaving the majority of human genetic diversity out of study.

The article you linked about prostate cancer seems like a good place to further understand this: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7219314/

It describes how therapies developed because they are effective in a single prostate cancer line didn't actually work for most people with prostate cancer, and that subsequent efforts to study therapies in *multiple* cell lines have not benefitted "Men of African Ancestry" because those cell lines are predominantly derived from "Men of European Ancestry".

Comment: Can you clarify how it comes about that "you have just one cell line labeled as 'African-American'...and *that one cell line is also mostly of European origin*"? Is it typical or atypical for a cell line from a random African-American patient to be "mostly of European origin"? Are you alluding to a specific cell line (e.g., HeLa)? I do see [mention](https://www.geni.com/people/Henrietta-Lacks/6000000014824235226) that Lacks's family was mixed-race ("Many of the black Lacks family were also descendants from the white Lacks family"). If that is your point, perhaps you can say it more directly.

Comment: @nanoman This is from the article in OP's question, which links to this paper: https://aacrjournals.org/cebp/article/28/6/1003/71948/Genetic-Ancestry-Analysis-Reveals "For instance, the 22Rv1 prostate cancer cell line was recently found to carry mixed genetic ancestry using a much smaller panel of markers. However, our more comprehensive analysis determined the 22Rv1 cell line carries 99% EUR ancestry. Most notably, the E006AA-hT prostate cancer cell line, classified as African American, was found to carry 92% EUR ancestry"

Comment: @nanoman Here's another descriptive article you might be interested in: https://cen.acs.org/biological-chemistry/cancer/Genetic-tests-reveal-cancer-cell/97/i10 Overall, though, my answer isn't particularly concerned with testing the premise, and cancer biology or ancestry determination are not my fields. I'm just answering OP's question about why someone would find this concerning and what the implications are for personalized medicine.

Comment: Could be a difference between self-reported ancestry, and genetic ancestry. Could be deliberate choice when completing the donation forms, or could be a typo or other accident - click the first choice in a drop down for example. By genetic ancestry, I mean clustering within large-scale population genetics studies such as [Thousand Genomes](https://www.internationalgenome.org/)

Comment: Thank for the answer, but if the article raised the issue, I suppose it is because the article does not "suppose an unknown difference that would impact the treatment's efficenciency" but because this difference is already a known phenomenon (like we already know that cell X has mutation Y for European but not for African)?
And a subsidiary question: if treatment's efficiency could be that much lowered/increased by ethnic difference, why does'nt it impact viruses or bacteria the same way ?

Comment: @totalMongot "I suppose it is because ... this difference is already a known phenomenon" I disagree - **the issue is if you don't study both you don't know what the differences are**, plus that it is known that there are poorer outcomes for prostate cancer for Black patients. I don't understand your statement "why does'nt it impact viruses or bacteria the same way", my answer does not mention viruses or bacteria.

Comment: @BryanKrause For first part I might have wrongly expressed but that's what I meant: some differences like outcome of prostate cancer are already known.
The statement is an extension from your answer: if diseases act differently because of cell differences, do viruses or bacteria act differently as well?

Comment: @totalMongot Different people have different responses to viruses and bacteria, yes, both within and between populations.

Comment: @BryanKrause Ok but is there a specific ethnic criteria about these differences? As for the previous example of prostate cancer?

Comment: @totalMongot What do you mean by "a specific ethnic criteria"? A historical example might include the decimation of populations native to the Americas after exposure to European illnesses, notably smallpox. Sickle cell trait would be another example.

Answer (score 3):

To supplement @Bryan Krause's excellent answer, I would add another with a very specific example of the kind of variation that could affect research.

Different people have very different responses to drugs, and [in many cases this variation is genetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pharmacogenomics). This variation exists across human populations, but [can also to some extent be non-uniform or "private" to specific populations](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/34652573/), meaning that sampling populations unevenly will give an inaccurate estimate of drug response variation. For example, [appropriate warfarin dosing varies dramatically across patients](https://health.ucsd.edu/for-health-care-professionals/anticoagulation-guidelines/warfarin/Pages/pharmacogenetics.aspx), based in part on genetic variation in known genes.

Thus, if all cell lines tested for response to a new drug candidate are of European descent, then you only understand the pharmacokinetics of that drug for a relatively small sample of overall human pharmacokinetic variation. This could lead to ineffective or lethal (!) drug dose guidance if initial studies in cell lines do not assay a representative range of human genetic variation. (Note: in general, many regulatory safeguards are in place hoping to prevent this kind of event.)

Expert reviews have in some cases [explicitly counseled personalized genetic testing](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/30916581/) to avoid such adverse drug reactions. This indicates that surveys at the population level are in fact inadequate to this problem, as they are too crude. So the issue is not really ethnic population representation, but rather the large scope of human genetic variation, to which apparent/reported ethnicity is only modestly correlated.

Answer (score -5):

Many of the works on "ethnic origin" are based on the chromosome Y. Majority of it (not all) does not have the pair to recombine (very small region still recombines with X), so essentially the same Y chromosome is passed from father to son, different only by infrequent mutations. Using these mutations, it is possible to construct a map of human origins, starting from [Y-chromosomal Adam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-chromosomal_Adam). This would reflect the history about how humans migrated, populating the Earth. The known "versions" of the Y chromosome are called "haplogroups", these are highlighted here by color ([image credit](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f8/Human_Y-DNA_phylogeny_and_haplogroup_distribution.png)):

[image]

There are obviously less groups than countries but very approximately this can be matched to the "ethnic origin" in cases like at least Russia, China, India or Australia, and to some ethnic groups that are known to be somewhat tied together, like the European region, for instance. In such cases, the origin of the parent line of ethnicity like Russian vs Ukrainian can be estimated by DNA sequencing of the Y chromosome.

**These chromosome signatures cannot be "assimilated"** by living for generations in a region where another type of Y is dominant. A hundred generations can pass and the simple scan of the Y chromosome would still show the true origins of the parent line.

There is obviously no reason to think that any version of Y chromosome is better than other. In general there not so many genes there. However anyway the Y chromosome is part of the cell.

Comment: The paper referenced in the OP's link is using SNPs from modern populations; so, if you have SNPs that are commonly found in people from Europe, and not commonly found in people elsewhere in the world, you can say you have a high probability of European ancestry. It's the same approach that commercial genome analysis companies offer to individuals. It has nothing to do with the Y chromosome or determining the migration of peoples in history/human origins. This answer also doesn't appear to answer the question asked about how the cells differ/what the concern is in this paper.

Comment: Please read the referenced sources, "has nothing to do with Y chromosome"

Comment: I'm talking about the OP's question, not your answer.

Comment: I think that my answer addresses the question well enough, sorry about this.

Comment: @h22 Thanks for the detailed answer. I understand that all (or at least significant part) of the difference between ethnic people is "coded" on the Y chromosome? Am I correct? Also, this means that these specificities are recurrent (not different between me and another guy of same ethnic origin?
PS: I upvoted because even if it focuses on the Y chromosom, it gives hindsights useful for the answer

Comment: @totalMongot no, ethnic differences are evenly spread over all chromosomes.

Comment: OK so Y chromosom is only one way to follow them. But in what do cells actually differ? Do their cell receptors, proteins differ?

Comment: @totalMongot there are all sorts of differences, depending on the genes we're talking about. Some populations with a certain genotype may be more susceptible to damage from a certain environmental toxin, for example, or get a certain kind of cancer more easily than another. The actual physical differences can be found at the protein level, or in the way genes and groups of genes are regulated in different ways due to differences in DNA sequences.

Comment: @h22 I honestly don't see how this answer addresses the question at all. OP was not asking about Y-Adam or the origin of ethnic differences at all.

Comment: Y haplogroups are good for tracking migration because they're strictly divergent (two Y hapologroups will never merge) and because they accumulate mutations at a predictable rate, giving information about timing.  They're not much good for anything else precisely *because* of that divergence: every other chromosome can get mixed up with others.  For example, an African-American male might be Y-hapologroup B-M150 (west African) with the entire rest of his DNA being European-typical variants.